# is it possible to apply left outer join on a partitioned table to get updated records?

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark-sql

Let us suppose I have one partitioned table and I want to fetch updated records daily between the latest(current date) and previous partition(one day back).is it possible through left outer join on this table by providing alias .
for example latest partition=2020-01-23

previous partition=2020-01-22

query="select a.column_names,b.column_names from db_name.table_name a left outer join db_name.table_name b on a.key=b.key where a.date=latest_date and b.date=previous_date"

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  How do you know if a record is updated?

Comment: schema={acct,acc_date,partition_date};data on partition_date(latest)=2020-01-2={1,2018-09-11,2020-01-23}{2,2018-08-11,2020-01-23}{3,2018-08-11,2020-01-23}
data on partition_date(-1 day)=2020-01-22 ={1,2018-09-11,2020-01-22}{2,2018-07-01,2020-01-22} conditions need to apply(left outer join)-1)a.acc_date<>b.acc_date 2)a.partition_date="2020-01-23"3)b.partition_date="2020-01-22" 4)join key is acct so a.acct=b.acct 5)coalesce on b.acc_date so that new record is fetched to resolve null issue.output:-{2,2018-08-11,2020-01-23}{2,2018-08-11,2020-01-23}
{3,2018-08-11,2020-01-23}{null,1900-01-01,null}

Comment: @GordonLinoff provided in the comment.Please provide your inputs.

Comment: I can know about updated record from column acc_date if it got changed for key(acct)